# showing popover with arrow without blocking parent view

Tags: ios, ios8, uipopovercontroller

I am developing in iOS8 and want to show a popover view with an arrow. However, i do not want to block the parent view. Also, tapping on the parent view should not dismiss the popover view.

When i use UIPopoverController the parent view is grayed out and tapping on it only dismisses the popover. What ui element should i use to achieve the required functionality?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a popover, or any other built in control. You'll probably have to implement it yourself using container view controllers and programmatic auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the views that should not be blocked by the pop over with the property `passthroughViews`.

```
let popOverViewController = PopOverViewController(...)
popOverViewController.popoverPresentationController?.passthroughViews = [view]
```